# Unable to start PostgreSQL Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I use Lubuntu 16.04 64 bit and I tried to install PostgreSQL using the Ubuntu software service.

I'm unable to run the server.

Many found the same problem and solved their issues.  I tried to follow their suggestions but nothing worked. Can you help me?

```
psql: could not connect to server: File o directory non esistente
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

when I run systemctl start postgresql-9.5.service I obtain

```
Failed to start postgresql-9.5.service: Unit postgresql-9.5.service not found.
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46983/discussion-on-question-by-user18228-unable-to-start-postgresql-ubuntu-16-04).